# org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager source code

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Would you please share the git repo url where i can download the source code for this class:
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager

I need to understand the framework before i can make any changes to my custom user store.

-Raj

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source  from [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/JDBCUserStoreManager.java)

Thanks
Isura

Comment: Thanks Isura for quicker response.